# How to highlight nested fields in Elasticsearch with query dsl or java api?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-java-api

I can get result for nested field with nested query but tt is impossible get highlighted result for nested field with below query. It can highlight only normal fields. Is there any way? I also need Java API. Using elasticsearch 5.4.1

There is sample index map with nested field:

```
PUT testix
{
  "mappings": {
    "topic": {
      "properties": {
        "section": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

sample document:

```
POST testix/topic/
{
  "id" : "5",
  "name" : "Document APIs",
  "section": [
    {
      "id" : "11",
      "topic_id" : "5",
      "type_id" : "3",
      "text" : "Semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id. Nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate."
    },
    {
      "id" : "12",
      "topic_id" : "5",
      "type_id" : "2",
      "text" : "Ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit. Odio eu feugiat pretium nibh. 2525"
    }
  ]
}

POST testix/topic/
{
  "id" : "7",
  "name" : "Search APIs",
  "section": [
    {
      "id" : "15",
      "topic_id" : "7",
      "type_id" : "3",
      "text" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 2525"
    },
    {
      "id" : "16",
      "topic_id" : "7",
      "type_id" : "2",
      "text" : "Nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim. Blandit massa enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut. "
    },
    {
      "id" : "17",
      "topic_id" : "7",
      "type_id" : "6",
      "text" : "Sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in. Laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim. "
    }
  ]
}

POST testix/topic/
{
  "id" : "9",
  "name" : "Request Body Search",
  "section": [
    {
      "id" : "3",
      "topic_id" : "9",
      "type_id" : "1",
      "text" : "Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Lorem sed risus ultricies tristique."
    },
    {
      "id" : "4",
      "topic_id" : "9",
      "type_id" : "2",
      "text" : "Egestas diam in arcu cursus. 2525 Tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus."
    },
    {
      "id" : "5",
      "topic_id" : "9",
      "type_id" : "4",
      "text" : "At consectetur lorem donec massa. Eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra."
    }
  ]
}

POST testix/topic/
{
  "id" : "19",
  "name" : "Request Body Search",
  "section": [
    {
      "id" : "13",
      "topic_id" : "19",
      "type_id" : "1",
      "text" : "Egestas diam in arcu cursus. Tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus."
    },
    {
      "id" : "15",
      "topic_id" : "19",
      "type_id" : "4",
      "text" : "Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi. "
    }
  ]
}
```

And query for results:

```
GET testix/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "section",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "section.text:2525",
                "fields": [
                  "section.text^2.0"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "section.type_id": ["3"]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<mark>"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</mark>"
    ],
    "fragment_size": 50,
    "number_of_fragments": 3,
    "fragmenter": "simple",
    "fields": {
      "section.text": {}
    }
  }
}
```